# Active Record returns ActiveRecord::Relation instead of flat object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am building a job application site. A student can apply for a job, a student has many applications, and each one of these applications has only one job posting it connects to. When I query the database, `ActiveRecord` is returning a `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which is an array. I can look at the properties of the object, but I have to go down a level.

Getting `object[0]` I have to do this to look at properties `object[0].id, object[0].name`.

Would like to do this `object.id, object.name`

This is my query:

```
@application = Application.where(user_id: current_user.id, posting_id: @posting.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Select the first element of the array:

```
@application = Application.
  where(user_id: current_user.id, posting_id: @posting.id).
  first
```

2) You can use `#find_by`

```
@application = Application.
  find_by(user_id: current_user.id, posting_id: @posting.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer your question

> Active Record returns ActiveRecord::Relation instead of flat object

```
@application = Application.where(user_id: current_user.id, posting_id: @posting.id)
```

- What’s returned by this query looks like an array of records but if
  we call `class` on it we’ll see that it’s actually an instance of
  `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

**`@application.class => ActiveRecord::Relation`**

**The Relation Class** -[Railscasts Episodes-239](http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough?view=asciicast)

> Having queries return an ActiveRecord::Relation object allows us to
> chain queries together and this Relation class is at the heart of the
> new query syntax. Let’s take a look at this class by searching through
> the ActiveRecord source code for a file called relation.rb.
>
> At the top of the class a number of constants are defined, one of
> which is a Struct. If you’re not familiar with structs these are a way
> of quickly defining a class dynamically by passing in a list of
> attributes in the constructor.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'

module ActiveRecord
  # = Active Record Relation
  class Relation
    JoinOperation = Struct.new(:relation, :join_class, :on)
    ASSOCIATION_METHODS = [:includes, :eager_load, :preload]
    MULTI_VALUE_METHODS = [:select, :group, :order, :joins, :where, :having]
    SINGLE_VALUE_METHODS = [:limit, :offset, :lock, :readonly, :create_with, :from]

    include FinderMethods, Calculations, SpawnMethods, QueryMethods, Batches
```

I would strongly suggest you to read out [Railscasts Episodes-239](http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough?view=asciicast) for more info.

Comment: Yes, this was very helpful. The first answer explained just how to get what I wanted, but the video link explains the why and what's going on behind the scenes.